# Remote validation on action with dateTime don't get proper value (Asp.Net Core 3.1)

Tags: asp.net-core

[image]

Model:

```
[Remote(action: "isDateOfTimeInUse", controller: "Contentpanel")]
public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
```

Action:

```
[AcceptVerbs("Get", "Post")]
public IActionResult isDateOfTimeInUse(DateTime dateOfBirth)
{

    
    var currentDate = DateTime.Now.Date.Year;
    
    if (currentDate - dateOfBirth.Date.Year <= 18)
    {
        
        return Json($"Date of birth " + dateOfBirth + " less then 18");
    }
    else
    {
        return Json(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's the default value for a `DateTime`. Unless something sets another value, `DateOfBirth` will be `0001-01-01 00:00`. Did the code try to validate an object whose `DateOfBirth` is left to its default? What does the client-side code look like?

Comment: Try using Fiddler or the browser's Network tab to see what's actually send to the server. It's quite likely that the value *is* a zero date

Comment: it work True. check your route or area path and check you network tab in your browser inspect.

Comment: I suggest that you provide us with your view code, because using these codes to test, I was able to successfully pass the dateOfBirth value.

Comment: Thanks all brother--- This is client side code.
---

<div class="form-group">
          <label asp-for="Input.DateOfBirth"></label>
            <input asp-for="Input.DateOfBirth" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Input.DateOfBirth" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>

Comment: @sakhawatHosen, can you tell us whether you are using `core mvc` or `razor page ` project? Why did you add `input.DateOfBirth` instead of directly `DateOfBirth` to bind?
And you can directly edit your post to add your complete front-end code, which will help us to help you solve the problem more easier.